# Show dialog to add device and tab

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, react.js, redux

I am just into redux. I am developing a dashboard using ReactJS redux and material-ui for components. It's a large app as my dashboard contains various features like add/edit/delete device, add/edit/delete tab, create card etc etc.

It's growing very large and I am just into redux, so I am not sure how I can refactor my code for better code structure of my app. The code that I am posting is about add tab which has name, icons (fetched from API) field and post it to an API.

**App.js**

```
import Header from '../containers/header';
import Content from '../containers/content';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
                  max_char: 32,
                  open: false,
                };
  }

  getChildContext() {
    return { muiTheme: getMuiTheme(baseTheme) };
  }

  handleToggle = () => this.setState({ open: !this.state.open });

  handleClose = () => this.setState({ open: false });

  handleOpen = () => this.setState({ open: true });


  handleChange(charLength) {
      this.setState({
        max_char: 32 - charLength.length
      });
  }

  render() {
      return (
            <div>
                <Header
                      tab={this.state.tabs}
                      open={this.state.open}
                      handleClose={this.handleClose}
                      handleToggle={this.handleToggle}
                />
                <Content
                    handleChange={this.handleChange}
                    remaningChar={this.state.max_char}
                />
            </div>
      );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**header.js**

```
import { selectTabIcon, CancelDeviceEvent, fetchTabs } from '../actions/index';

class Header extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
      this.props.fetchTabs();
  }

  render() {
    const tabs = _.map(this.props.fetchTab.tabs, (tab) =>
         <span className="tab" key={tab.id}><a href="">{tab.name}</a></span>
    );

    const navigation = (
      <div className="nav-icon" style={{ margin: '12px 40px 0px 10px' }}>
        <i
          className="material-icons md-23"
          id="1"
          onClick={(event) => this.props.selectTabIcon(event)}
        >
          delete
        </i>
        <i
          className="material-icons md-23"
          id="2"
          onClick={(event) => this.props.selectTabIcon(event)}
        >
          add_circle
        </i>
      </div>
    );

    return (
      <div>
        <AppBar
            title={tabs}
            iconElementRight={navigation}
            onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={this.props.handleToggle}
            style={{ background: '#fff' }}
        />
        <Drawer
            width={200}
            open={this.props.open}
            containerStyle={{ background: '#2f4050' }}
        >
          <MenuItem onTouchTap={this.props.handleClose}>Logo</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem onTouchTap={this.props.handleClose}>Menu Item 2</MenuItem>
          <Link to="/">Create A Device</Link>
        </Drawer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    iconList: state.iconList,
    fetchTab: state.fetchTab
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({
    selectTabIcon,
    CancelDeviceEvent,
    fetchTabs
  }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Header);


const Content = (props) =>
    (
      <div className="content-section">
        <DeviceEventList />
        <DeviceDialog onChange={props.handleChange} />
        <DeviceList />
        <TabDialog />
      </div>
    );

export default Content;
```

**tab-dialog.js**

```
class TabDialog extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
      this.props.fetchIcons();
      this.props.fetchTabs();
  }

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.addTab(this.state.name, this.state.icon);
  }

  renderAddTab() {
    const listOfIcon = _.map(this.props.fetchIcon.icons, (icon) => {
                          return {
                              text: icon.name,
                              id: icon.id,
                              value: <MenuItem primaryText={icon.name} />
                            };
                        });
    return (
      <div className="device-action">
        <Dialog
            title="Add a Tab"
            modal={false}
            bodyStyle={{ background: '#fff' }}
            contentStyle={customContentStyle}
            actionsContainerStyle={{ background: '#fff' }}
            titleStyle={{ background: '#fff', color: '#1ab394' }}
            open={this.props.createTab.open}
            onRequestClose={this.props.closeTabIcon}
        >
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <div className="tab-name">
        <TextField
          floatingLabelText="Name"
          ref="name"
          floatingLabelStyle={{ color: '#1ab394' }}
          floatingLabelFocusStyle={{ color: '#1db4c2' }}
          underlineStyle={{ borderColor: '#1ab394' }}
          onChange={(name) => { this.setState({ name: name.target.value }); }}
        />
        </div>
        <div className="icon">
        <AutoComplete
          floatingLabelText="select any icon"
          ref="icon"
          filter={AutoComplete.noFilter}
          openOnFocus
          dataSource={listOfIcon}
          textFieldStyle={{ borderColor: '#1ab394' }}
          className="autocomplete"
          onNewRequest={(e) => { this.setState({ icon: e.id }); }}
        />
        </div>
        <button className="btn">Save</button>
        </form>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
  );
  }

  renderDeleteTab() {
    const actions = [
      <FlatButton
        label="Cancel"
        primary
        onTouchTap={this.props.closeTabIcon}
      />,
      <FlatButton
        label="Delete"
        primary
        keyboardFocused
        onTouchTap={this.props.closeTabIcon}
      />,
    ];
    return (
    <div className="tab-action">
      <Dialog
          title="Delete"
          actions={actions}
          modal={false}
          bodyStyle={{ background: '#fff' }}
          contentStyle={customContentStyle}
          actionsContainerStyle={{ background: '#fff' }}
          titleStyle={{ background: '#fff', color: '#1ab394' }}
          open={this.props.createTab.open}
          onRequestClose={this.props.closeTabIcon}
      >
      <TextField
        floatingLabelText="Name"
        floatingLabelStyle={{ color: '#1ab394' }}
        floatingLabelFocusStyle={{ color: '#1db4c2' }}
        underlineStyle={{ borderColor: '#1ab394' }}
      />
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
  }


  render() {
    const iconSelected = this.props.createTab;
    if (!iconSelected) {
      return (<span />);
    }
    if (iconSelected.id === '1') {
      return (this.renderDeleteTab());
    }
    if (iconSelected.id === '2') {
      return (this.renderAddTab());
    }
}
}

function mapStateToProps({ iconList, createTab, fetchIcon, fetchTab }) {
  return {
    iconList,
    createTab,
    fetchIcon,
    fetchTab
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({
    addTab,
    selectTabIcon,
    closeTabIcon,
    CancelDeviceEvent,
    fetchIcons,
    fetchTabs
  }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TabDialog);
```

**tab-create-reducers.js**

```
const initial = {
  posting: false,
  posted: false,
  tabs: [],
  error: null
};

export const postTab = (state = initial, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'POST_TAB_START':
      return { ...state, posting: false };
    case 'POST_TAB_FAILURE':
      return { ...state, error: action.payload };
    case 'POST_TAB':
      return { ...state, posting: false, posted: true, tabs: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const initialState = {
  fetching: false,
  fetched: true,
  icons: [],
  error: null,
};

export const fetchIconReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_ICONS_START':
      return { ...state, fetching: true };
    case 'FETCH_ICONS_ERROR':
      return { ...state, fetching: false, error: action.payload };
    case 'RECIEVE_ICONS':
      return { ...state, fetching: false, fetched: true, icons: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const firstState = {
  fetching: false,
  fetched: true,
  tabs: [
          { name: 'dashboard', id: 1, icon: 'dashboard' }
      ],
  error: null,
};

export const fetchTab = (state = firstState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'RECIEVE_TAB':
      return { ...state, fetching: false, fetched: true, tabs: action.payload };
    case 'FETCH_TAB_ERROR':
      return { ...firstState, ...state, hydrated: true, fetching: false, error: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**actions.js**

```
export function fetchIcons() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_ICONS_START' });
    axios.get('http://192.168.1.103:8000/rest-api/dev/icons/')
    .then((response) => {
      dispatch({ type: 'RECIEVE_ICONS', payload: response.data });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_ICONS_ERROR', payload: err });
    });
  };
}

export function addTab(name, icon) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'POST_TAB_START' });
    return axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://192.168.1.103:8000/rest-api/ui/tabs/',
      headers: {
        'X-CSRFToken': CSRF_TOKEN,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      data: {
        name,
        icon
      },
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log('response', response);
      dispatch({ type: 'POST_TAB',
                 payload: response.data });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch({ type: 'POST_TAB_FAILURE', payload: err });
    });
  };
}

export function fetchTabs() {
  return dispatch => {
    axios.get('/rest-api/ui/tabs/')
    .then((response) => {
      dispatch({ type: 'RECIEVE_TAB', payload: response.data });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_TAB_ERROR', payload: err });
    });
  };
}

export function selectTabIcon(selectTab) {
  return {
    type: 'TAB_ICON_SELECTED',
    id: selectTab.target.id,
    open: true
  };
}

export function closeTabIcon() {
  return {
    type: 'TAB_ICON_CLOSE',
    open: false
  };
}
```

I'm just adding tab has such lines of code. Editing, deleting is still left also other tons of features. Refactoring the code will slightly reduce it and I can do on other features too. Please do review on my code and design pattern for scalable app mainly reducer and action part.